# how to set local rcParams or rcParams for one figure in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am writing a plotting function in `python` using `matplotlib`. The user can specify some things, e.g. "tick lines". The easiest way would be to change the `rcParams`, but those are global properties, so all new plots will have tick lines after that plotting function was called.

Is there a way to set the plotting defaults specifically for just one figure?

Or is there at least a good way to change the properties for one plotting-function and then change them back to the values that were used before (not necessarily the `rcdefaults`)?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use the `rc_context` function in a `with` statement, which will set the rc parameters with a dictionary you provide for the block indented below and then reset them to whatever they were before after the block. For example:

```
with plt.rc_context({"axes.grid": True, "grid.linewidth": 0.75}):
    f, ax = plt.subplots()  # Will make a figure with a grid
    ax.plot(x, y)

f, ax = plt.subplots()  # Will make a figure without a grid
ax.plot(x, y)
```

Comment: Having globally-defined parameters only looks like a really bad design solution.

Comment: Seems like the only way, it's a bit inconvenient though to have a new indent.