# Is there a way to set the plotting global properties specifically for just one figure in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

I do realize this has already been addressed here (e.g.,.[how to set local rcParams or rcParams for one figure in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22792779/how-to-set-local-rcparams-or-rcparams-for-one-figure-in-matplotlib))  Nevertheless, I hope this question was different.

I have a plotting function in python with `matplotlib` that includes `global properties`, so all new plots will have updated with the `global properties`.

```
def catscatter(data,colx,coly,cols,color=['grey','black'],ratio=10,font='Helvetica',save=False,save_name='Default'):
    '''
    This function creates a scatter plot for categorical variables. It's useful to compare two lists with elements in common.
    '''

    df = data.copy()
    # Create a dict to encode the categeories into numbers (sorted)
    colx_codes=dict(zip(df[colx].sort_values().unique(),range(len(df[colx].unique()))))
    coly_codes=dict(zip(df[coly].sort_values(ascending=False).unique(),range(len(df[coly].unique()))))
    
    # Apply the encoding
    df[colx]=df[colx].apply(lambda x: colx_codes[x])
    df[coly]=df[coly].apply(lambda x: coly_codes[x])
    
    
    # Prepare the aspect of the plot
    plt.rcParams['xtick.bottom'] = plt.rcParams['xtick.labelbottom'] = False
    plt.rcParams['xtick.top'] = plt.rcParams['xtick.labeltop'] = True
    plt.rcParams['font.sans-serif']=font
    
    plt.rcParams['xtick.color']=color[-1]
    plt.rcParams['ytick.color']=color[-1]
    plt.box(False)

    
    # Plot all the lines for the background
    for num in range(len(coly_codes)):
        plt.hlines(num,-1,len(colx_codes),linestyle='dashed',linewidth=2,color=color[num%2],alpha=0.5)
    for num in range(len(colx_codes)):
        plt.vlines(num,-1,len(coly_codes),linestyle='dashed',linewidth=2,color=color[num%2],alpha=0.5)
        
    # Plot the scatter plot with the numbers
    plt.scatter(df[colx],
               df[coly],
               s=df[cols]*ratio,
               zorder=2,
               color=color[-1])
    
    # Change the ticks numbers to categories and limit them
    plt.xticks(ticks=list(colx_codes.values()),labels=colx_codes.keys(),rotation=90)
    plt.yticks(ticks=list(coly_codes.values()),labels=coly_codes.keys())


    # Save if wanted
    if save:
        plt.savefig(save_name+'.png')
```

Below are the properties that I'm using inside the function,

```
plt.rcParams['xtick.bottom'] = plt.rcParams['xtick.labelbottom'] = False
plt.rcParams['xtick.top'] = plt.rcParams['xtick.labeltop'] = True
```

I want these `properties` to apply only when I call the `catscatter` function.

Is there a way to set the plotting **`global properties`** specifically for just one figure, without impacting other plots in **`jupyter notebook`**?

Or is there at least a good way to change the properties for one plotting function and then change them back to the values that were used before (not necessarily the `rcdefaults`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To only change the properties of one figure, you can just use the relevant method on the Figure or Axes instance rather than using the `rcParams`.

In this case, it looks like you want to set the x-axis label and ticks to appear on the top of the plot rather than the bottom. You can use the following to achieve exactly that.

```
ax.xaxis.set_label_position('top')
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('top')
```

Consider the following minimal example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.set_xlabel('label')

ax.xaxis.set_label_position('top')
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('top')
```

[image]

Comment: Applying with the axes didn't work for me? Maybe due to my coding limitations. Included my complete working code. Could you help me with that?

Comment: in your code you don't define what `ax` is... so you can just use `ax=plt.gca()` somewhere before using `.set_label_position()` and `.set_ticks_position()`

Comment: instead of `plt.rcParams` , I should use `.set_label_position()` and `.set_ticks_position()`  with `ax` right?

Comment: yes, exactly. A suggestion would be to create the Figure and Axes instances before you start plotting on the using `plt.subplots` as I did in my minimal example, and then use the relevant [object-oriented methods](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/index.html#the-object-oriented-api) to plot your data and set the axes labels, etc., so you can be sure all your methods are working on the correct figure and axes instances.